# Words containing "ff" in PDF created by LyX are not searchable

Tags: pdf, ligatures, copy-paste

My setting under LyX "Document" command: 
language encoding--unicode utf-8; 
output--default

A minimal example:

type "coefficient" and generate PDF, then search it in PDF

result: not showing up

I tried "tariff" and other words containing "ff", still get
 the same problem.

**Update on 9th Nov 2016**

I can confirm that the LyX solution offered to the question to which I have duplicated solves my problem. So just paste the following into the preamble:

```
  \usepackage{cmap}
  \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
```

Comment: That is *not* a **Minimum Example** :)

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner, I have fixed the typo if that is what you suggest: )

Comment: That was not what he wanted to say... See: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of LaTeX replacing the two letters `ff` with what is called a ligature in typography, a single symbol representing the two letters. This looks more beautiful, because instead of having two letters, each one with a horizontal line (and thus a tiny space between those lines), you have one single horizontal line somehow connecting the two letters. This also happens for `fi` and some other combinations.

You might want to try the `cmap` package.

I just tried the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

tariff

\end{document}
```

And could not reproduce the error; with or without the two packages included. This was with Apple's Preview.app. Maybe you have to update your PDF viewer?

Anyway, providing a minimal working example would be good for further investigations.

Comment: I installed cmap, reconfigured LyX under "Tools", but still not searchable...I use the latest Adobe DC reader.

Comment: Then please set up an MWE (see my comment above). Have you tried my example document? Have you tried other PDF readers? What operating system do you use?

Comment: I tried your example, and Adobe Acrobat XI pro too, still not searchable. I use Windows 10.

Comment: Some experts have pointed to a previous question to which I have duplicated. It also had a LyX solution which worked for me. Thx a lot anyway!